# Overriding django admin dashboard and adding logic on it

Tags: django, admin, models, dashboard

I would like to know how could I add some logic on my admin dashboard. I need to make queries on three different models and show data on Dashboard template but still can't handle the template extention with different models data.

Thanks!

Comment: More specifics please.

Answer (score 0):

Accomplishing what I was planning to do looked weird. I would need to change the base_site.html rendering view to show up these information, or something else that I don't know how to deal with, so, what i did was:

- Extend admin/base.html on /templates/admin loading original data, and overriding some blocks

> {% extends "admin/base.html" %}

```
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}
    {{ title }}
{% endblock %}
{% block branding %}
    <h1 id="site-name">Administration</h1>

{% endblock %}


{% block nav-global %}
    <center>
        <a href="/reports" class="link-button"><button>Reports</button></a>
        <a href="/report_graphs" class="link-button"><button>Graphs</button></a>
    </center>
{% endblock %}
```

It's working fine by now, but still don't know how to deal with admin view of base_index.html